# Sitecore Search Lucene Ranking

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

How can I set the `priority` of fields when I'm searching with `Lucene .Net`

For example i have :

```
Item 1
         field 1 =contain "search text"
         field 2 ="bla bla"
Item 2
         field 1 = "loren ipsun"
         field 2 = contain "search text"
```

What should I do to have on results, top item : item 1 first from list, item 2 second one,etc.

Comment: Please correct your sentence on last line of your question. Otherwise it will be difficult for other user to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question. You want to have hits on a specific field boosted more then on another field and for this you can use the BoostFactor. You can boost the Query that you are using to search in Field one. For example if you use a Query qryName = queryParser.parse(keyword) you can do the following:

```
qryName.SetBoost(1000f);
```

This will boost hits on the specific part of your search that your specified in that query. You should therefor use 2 Query's for both fields and boost the first Query in which you search field 1.
You can vary in the boostfactor untill is suits your needs.

Hope this helps ;)